# Executa no eclipse mas quando gero o jar não

Tags: java

```
package teste;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Mover {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {


String destino = "C:"+ File.separator +"Windows"+ File.separator +"system32"+ File.separator +"drivers"+ File.separator +"etc"+ File.separator ;


Path sourceFile = Paths.get("src","hosts");
Path targetFile = Paths.get(destino,"hosts");

Files.copy(sourceFile, targetFile,StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "ARQUIVO HOSTS TROCADO.");
}
}
```

da esse erro

> ```
> C:\Users\jerso\Desktop>java -jar trocador.jar
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
>
> Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: src\hosts
>         at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileCopy.copy(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.copy(Unknown Source)
>         at java.nio.file.Files.copy(Unknown Source)
>         at pergunta.Mover.main(Mover.java:24)
>         ... 5 more
> ```

Comment: Essa pasta ai, até onde sei, é protegida contra leitura pelo windows. Nada sem permissão de administrador consegue sobrescrever nada dentro da pasta C:\Windows. Mostre o erro que ocorre ao executar, iniciando o jar de um prompt de comando.

Comment: Não adicione aqui, clique em EDITAR  e adicione na sua pergunta.

Comment: src não é um caminho válido. Olha como você está passando, como uma string. Provavelmente esse src deveria ser uma variavel com um caminho, como a variavel destino.

Comment: que comando eu uso para localizar o arquivo dentro do jar
     String source = getClass().getResource("host");